# Keychain.choosePrivateKeyAlias not showing dialog in Android 10

Tags: android, certificate, android-10.0, android-security

`Keychain.choosePrivateKeyAlias` was showing a dialog prompt allowing the user to install the CA certificates in Android API Level 9 and below. There were some changes in the Keychain API in Android 10 as specified in the docs [*"KeyChain behavior changes and improvements"*](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#keychain).

It will be helpful if some can provide suggestions to bring the install certificate prompt back in Android 10!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we have to write our own UI dialogue to install the certificate.

You could try to use the following code.

```
private void installCertificate()
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open(MY_CERT));
        byte[] keychain = new byte[bis.available()];
        bis.read(keychain);

        Intent installIntent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
        X509Certificate x509 = X509Certificate.getInstance(keychain);
        installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, x509.getEncoded());
        installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, MY_CERT);
        startActivityForResult(installIntent, INSTALL_KEYCHAIN_CODE);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (CertificateException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (requestCode == INSTALL_KEYCHAIN_CODE) 
    {
        switch (resultCode) 
        {  
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                doTheTask();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                finish();
                break;                  
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

But maybe it won't work for Android 11
https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/android-11-trust-ca-certificates/